# How to specify output path for crowdin cli translations?

Tags: config, crowdin

I am using Crowdin CLI to download translations. I want to download the files from one path (flat, to be exact, so "/file.ext") and to a path structured in another way e.g. "/folder/folder2/file.ext".

How do I do that?

My current crowdin.yml that works in downloading from a flat structure to a flat structure:

```
"preserve_hierarchy": true

files: [
 {
  "source" : "/**/*.*",
  "translation" : "/%locale%/%original_file_name%"
 },
 {
  "source" : "/**/*.*",
  "translation" : "/%two_letters_code%/%original_file_name%"
 }
]
```

Extending the "translation" path to the desired "/folder/folder2/file.ext" causes the following error:

```
Downloaded translations don't match the current project configuration. 
The translations for the following sources will be omitted (...)
```

Answer (score 1):

CLI configuration should match the project's structure + the path on your laptop. Refer to this guide on the matter:
https://developer.crowdin.com/configuration-file/#configuration-file-structure

Also, Crowdin has an excellent community, I'm sure you'll find a bit of additional advice there

https://community.crowdin.com/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).